# SPI issues while using STM32 as slave

Tags: stm32, spi, esp32, hal

I am using STM32L496RG and have configured it as a slave as follows

```c
/* SPI1 init function */
void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

I am simply trying to receive data from ESP32 (master) and transmit some data back to ESP32.

```c
void state_standby()
{
    #ifdef ESP_PRESENT
    if(HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,(uint8_t*)cmd_from_esp, sizeof(cmd_from_esp), 200)!=HAL_OK){
            Error_Handler();
        }
    else{
        if (cmd_from_esp[0] == 'S' && cmd_from_esp[1] == 'T' && cmd_from_esp[2] == 'A' && cmd_from_esp[3] == 'R' && cmd_from_esp[4] == 'T'){
                if  (HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t*)cmd_from_esp,sizeof(cmd_from_esp),200)!= HAL_OK){
            Error_Handler();
    }
            set_operating_state(TEST_SET);
        }       
    }

    #else 
    set_operating_state(ACTIVE);
    flash_page_count = 0;
    esp_page_count = 0;
    #endif
}
```

But when I run my code, even though nothing is being received, my code goes into the `Error_Handler` function inside `HAL_SPI_Receive`and goes to state 0x03 (`HAL_TIMEOUT`). But, nevertheless, when it receives data from ESP32, it does change its state is able to receive the data properly. But the problem I am facing is during my transmission. If I receive START in STM32, I send the same thing back to ESP32, but on the ESP32, I receive STARS. I am not sure if it this is because of `HAL_ERROR` or due to coding on ESP32 which is below -

```
for(i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++){
      if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()){
        if(serverClients[i].available()){
          //get data from the telnet client and push it to the UART
          while(serverClients[i].available())
          {
            data_array[j]=(serverClients[i].read());  
            j++;    
          }
          for(m = 0;m<j-2;m++)
            vspiCommand();

        j=0;
      }
      }

      else {
        if (serverClients[i]) {
          serverClients[i].stop();
        }

      }

    }

void vspiCommand() {

  //Serial.println("in vspi");
  //use it as you would the regular arduino SPI API
  vspi->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(VSPI_SS, LOW); //pull SS slow to prep other end for transfer
 { 
  received_data[m] = vspi->transfer(data_array[m]); 
  //vspi->transfer(data_array[m]);
//  Serial.print(data_array[m]);
//  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print(received_data[m]);
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.println(m); 
 }
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(VSPI_SS, HIGH); //pull ss high to signify end of data transfer
  vspi->endTransaction();
}
```

ESP32 receives data through my phone into data_array buffer and sends it to STM32, which in turn is sending the received data back to ESP32 which it is trying to read.

EDIT - I have modified the code a bit. Now, I am using `HAL_SPI_Receive_IT`and it stops hanging on that error. Made the following change in Slave side.

```
while (1)
  {

   if(HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(&hspi1,(uint8_t*)buffer,sizeof(buffer))!=HAL_OK){
            Error_Handler();
        }



        while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);


        }
}

void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{

    if(HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t*)buffer,sizeof(buffer),200)!=HAL_OK){
            Error_Handler();

}
```

And following changes in master side -

```
 for(i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++){
      if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()){
        if(serverClients[i].available()){
          //get data from the telnet client and push it to the UART

          while(serverClients[i].available())
          {
            // read the bytes incoming from the client:
             char thisChar = serverClients[i].read();
             inData += thisChar;
             data_array[j]=thisChar;
             j++;
            // echo to the server what's been received to confirm we have the string
            if (thisChar == '\n')
                   {
//                     Serial.print("\nreceived:");
//                     Serial.print(inData);

                     for(int i=0;i<(j-2);i++)
                     {
                     vspi->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
                      digitalWrite(VSPI_SS, LOW); //pull SS slow to prep other end for transfer
                     { 
                      received_data[i] = vspi->transfer(data_array[i]);
        //              Serial.print(data_array[m]);
        //              Serial.print('\t');
                      Serial.print(received_data[i]);
                      Serial.print('\t');
                      Serial.println(i); 
                     }
                      digitalWrite(VSPI_SS, HIGH); //pull ss high to signify end of data transfer
                      vspi->endTransaction();
                     }  
                     serverClients[i].write(received_data, (j-2)); 
                     j=0;   
                   }

          }

           }
```

The slave(STM32) is able to receive the data properly, but the master(ESP32) receives the proper data only alternately. For example, if I send hello, it receives eeeee(second character of whichever data I'm trying to send). If I send hello again, it receives hello. [image]. (In the image, you can see the slave received data in `buffer` array and master received data in COM2 port.

Comment: My advice: use `indent` against your source code, it's unreadable!

Comment: It's not clear, does your slave receive correctly or not ? What is the SPI frequency ? (SCK)

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean -yes, the slave receives correctly. SCK is 5Mhz.